# save print output to .txt

Tags: python, regex, output

I have a script that export all email adresses from a .txt document and print all the email adresses. 
I would like to save this to list.txt, and if possible delete duplicates,
but it will give the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mail.py", line 44, in <module>
    notepad.write(email.read())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Script:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
import os.path
import re

regex = re.compile(("([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`"
                    "{|}~-]+)*(@|\sat\s)(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.|"
                    "\sdot\s))+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)"))

def file_to_str(filename):
    """Returns the contents of filename as a string."""
    with open(filename) as f:
        return f.read().lower() # Case is lowered to prevent regex mismatches.

def get_emails(s):
    """Returns an iterator of matched emails found in string s."""
    # Removing lines that start with '//' because the regular expression
    # mistakenly matches patterns like 'http://foo@bar.com' as '//foo@bar.com'.
    return (email[0] for email in re.findall(regex, s) if not     email[0].startswith('//'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = OptionParser(usage="Usage: python %prog [FILE]...")
    # No options added yet. Add them here if you ever need them.
    options, args = parser.parse_args()

    if not args:
        parser.print_usage()
        exit(1)

    for arg in args:
        if os.path.isfile(arg):
            for email in get_emails(file_to_str(arg)):
                #print email
                notepad = open("list.txt","wb")
                notepad.write(email.read())
                notepad.close()

        else:
            print '"{}" is not a file.'.format(arg)
            parser.print_usage()
```

Comment: Try this: `notepad.write(email)`. Just email without .read()

Comment: Like @neverwalkaloner wrote, remove `.read()` from `email.read()`. In addition, to remove duplicates you could convert the returned value of `get_emails` to a set with `for email in set(get_emails(file_to_str(arg))):`.

Comment: When I remove .read() it shows only 1 email adres in list.txt when I use print email is shows a couple of hundred. when refreshing the list.txt while the extraction is busy the email adres change's but it only shows 1.

Comment: Change your regex to [`(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_\`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_\`{|}~-]+)*(?:@|\sat\s)(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(?:\.|\sdot\s))+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)`](https://regex101.com/r/sSjM7h/1).

Comment: When I change the regex, it gaves the error:  " SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file mail.py on line 16, but no encoding declared; "

Answer (score 0):

> When I remove .read() it shows only 1 email adres in list.txt when I
>   use print email is shows a couple of hundred. when refreshing the
>   list.txt while the extraction is busy the email adres change's but it
>   only shows 1.

This is because you have `open()` and `close()` within the loop, i. e. the file is written anew for each `email` and you end up with only the last address line written. Change the loop to:

```
            notepad = open("list.txt", "wb")
            for email in get_emails(file_to_str(arg)):
                #print email
                notepad.write(email)
            notepad.close()
```

or even better:

```
            with open("list.txt", "wb") as notepad:
              for email in get_emails(file_to_str(arg)):
                #print email
                notepad.write(email)
```